# Prove triangle inequality from definition of absolute value

Tags: real-analysis

Define the absolute value of a real number $x$ as $\lvert\,x\,\rvert = \max\{x, −x\}$.
Prove the triangle inequality:
$$\lvert\,x + y\,\rvert \leq \lvert\,x\,\rvert + \lvert\,y\,\rvert,$$
for any $x, y \in \mathbb R$. When does the equality hold?

Comment: What are your thoughts? Did you try something?

Answer (score 1):

We have for $a \in \mathbb R$:

$(*)$  $\pm a \le \lvert\,a\,\rvert$.

Case 1: $x+y \ge 0$. Then $\lvert\,x+y\,\rvert =x+y \le \lvert\,x\,\rvert+\lvert\,y\,\rvert$, by $(*)$.

Case 1: $x+y < 0$. Then $\lvert\,x+y\,\rvert =-(x+y)=-x+(-y) \le \lvert\,x\,\rvert+\lvert\,y\,\rvert$, by $(*)$.

Answer (score 1):

$\lvert\,x+y\,\rvert=\max{\pm( x+y)}\leq \pm x+\pm y \leq \max{\pm x}+\max{\pm y}=\lvert\,x\,\rvert+\lvert\,y\,\rvert$

Answer (score 1):

We can avoid dealing with separate cases by performing some algebra to obtain a simpler but equivalent inequality.

As both sides of the inequality $|x+y| \leq |x| + |y|$ are nonnegative, we can obtain an equivalent inequality by squaring both sides:
$$|x+y|^2 \leq (|x|+|y|)^2 = |x|^2 + 2|x||y| + |y|^2$$
Since $x$ and $y$ are real, we have $|x+y|^2 = (x+y)^2$, and similarly we can remove the absolute values from the other square terms to get 
$$(x+y)^2 \leq x^2 + 2|x||y| + y^2$$
Expanding the left hand side gives us
$$x^2 + 2xy + y^2 \leq x^2 + 2|x||y| + y^2$$
Subtracting $x^2 + y^2$ from both sides, we obtain
$$2xy \leq 2|x||y| = 2|xy|$$
and so 
$$xy \leq |xy|$$
All of the inequalities are equivalent, so the original inequality holds if and only if $xy \leq |xy|$.

Now observe that if $w$ is any real number, the inequality $w \leq |w|$ is always true, and equality holds if and only if $w$ is nonnegative.

Applying this to $w = xy$ allows us to conclude that the original inequality holds for any real $x$ and $y$, and equality holds if and only if $xy \geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Upvoted Fred's answer above.  Equality, is, of course, when both x and y are on the same side of zero.

i.e. $x \geq 0$ and $y\geq 0$

OR

$x \leq0$ and $y\leq0$

Answer (score 0):

$x+y\leq \max (x,-x)+y\leq \max (x,-x)+\max (y,-y)=|x|+|y|.$

$-(x+y)=(-x)+(-y)\leq \max (-x,x)+(-y)\leq \max (-x,x)+\max(-y,y)=|x|+|y|.$

Therefore $|x+y|=\max (x+y,-(x+y))\leq |x|+|y|.$

A useful corollary is $|u-v|\geq |u|-|v|$: We have $|u-v|+|v|\geq |(u-v)+v|=|u|.$

If $x<0<y$ then $x+y<y=|y|<|x|+|y|$ and $-(x+y)=(-x)+(-y)=|x|-|y|<|x|+|y|$, so $|x+y|<|x|+|y|.$

Interchanging $x$ and $y$ in the previous sentence, we also see that if $y<0<x$ then $|y+x|<|y|+|x|.$

If $x\geq 0$ and $y\geq 0$ then $x+y=|x|+|y|$ which implies $|x+y|\geq |x|+|y|\geq |x+y|.$

If $x\leq 0$ and $y\leq 0$ then $-(x+y)=(-x)+(-y)=|x|+|y|$ which implies $|x+y|\geq |x|+|y|\geq |x+y|.$